# Object added to Array is immediately 'out of scope'

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, scope, nsmutablearray

I'm new to Objective C and I could really use some assistance.

I have created a class called Agent.  The Agent class contains the following method:

```
    + (Agent *)agentWithName:(NSString*)theName {

        Agent *agent = [[[Agent alloc] init] autorelease];

        agent.agentName = theName;
        return agent;
    }
```

Then from my root view controller I want to loop through a Dictionary of names creating an Agent object for each name and adding that Agent object to an NSMutableArray:

```
    for (id object in dictArray) {
        NSString *agentName = [object objectForKey:@"name"];
        [self.myAgents addObject:[Agent agentWithName:agentName]];
    }
```

The trouble is that as soon as the execution has passed `[self.myAgents addObject:[Agent agentWithName:agentName]];`, all the agent objects inside of the NSMutableArray `self.myAgents` are listed by the debugger as 'out of scope'.  This causes an EXC_BAD_ACCESS later in my code when I try to access objects in that array.  Objects are getting added to the array (at least they're showing up in the XCode debugger) they're just out of scope, but they're out of scope before even exiting the for loop.  Can anyone please explain what I'm doing wrong?  I'm almost certain it has to do with my lack of understanding for memory management.  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Are you certain about cause and effect here? gdb is sometimes quite dumb and says something is out of scope when it really isn't. But I doubt the debugger output is the reason for "This causes an EXC_BAD_ACCESS later in my code when I try to access objects in that array."

Comment: Agree with Ole. Doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code you've currently posted. Can we see the declaration and any assignment of your 'myAgents' variable? I suspect that's what's getting the bad access.

Comment: I agree with the comments above, but I will add that it is often somewhat difficult to track down the actual source of EXC-BAD-ACCESS. It does indicate that **something** was over-released, but it can be difficult to determine exactly what it was. That's _why_ it would be helpful to see the declaration and assignment code. There's more discussion and some good answers on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7691096/962009.

Comment: "Out of scope" has absolutely nothing to do with it. An object cannot be out of scope, because objects don't have scope. Variables have scope, but variables don't control object lifetimes. So you're looking in the wrong place. The "out of scope" error is just a flaw in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I would have created a simple NSObject class for Agent:

```
//  Agent.h

@interface Agent : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *agentName;

- (id)initWithAgentName:(NSString *)name;

@end

// Agent.m

@implementation Agent

- (id)initWithAgentName:(NSString *)name
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization

        self.agentName = name;
    }
    return self;
}
```

And then create instances like:

```
// Assuming dictArray contains NSDictionaries like your code implies
for (id dictionary in dictArray)
{
    NSString *agentName = [dictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
    Agent *agent = [[Agent alloc] initWithAgentName:agentName];
    [self.myAgents addObject:agent];
}
```