# Array, memory management

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, xcode, ios5

I have some code where I implemented undo functionality, the undo function is as follows:

```
- (void) undo
{
    drawImage.image = pathArray.lastObject;
    [pathArray removeLastObject];
}
```

Then I have one more function to capture the current image from the screen; in this function I am getting EXC_Bad_ACCESS error on this

`[pathArray removeLastObjectatIndex:0];`

No other calls of functions are made in this part of program. Maybe there could be a problem of moving whole array, but I don't want to use undo manager.

Is there any better way, to get the last object of an array and then remove the first one and move whole array by one?

Notice : path array is `MutableArray *patharray;`

Thanks all!=)

I just don't have and idea how to solve this. I didn't find any solution in the official docs.

Comment: I think you have a couple questions in here, but I'm not sure.  1) You're getting an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS trying to use your array, chances are you don't have a strong reference to the array anymore and it has been deallocated.  2) You'd like to do something with the items in your array? Sounds like a stack, where you want to pop the top item off.

Comment: yes, I have 5 objects in it. And it shows this error BAD Access...and there is another curiosity about this. I use it for the first time, okay, use it for the second time, okay, but if i call it third time, app crashes on BAD ACCESS ERROR...:(

Comment: Looks like your memory is corrupted.  `pathArray` may have been released, but you kept a pointer to it.  See http://loufranco.com/blog/files/Understanding-EXC_BAD_ACCESS.html or similar articles on debugging EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: Can you include code where you alloc / release / autorelease `pathArray`?  This would help narrow where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, this program would not likely be *reachable* -- It implies there is nothing to 'undo' in many contexts, and the option should not be given. Your problem often ultimately lies upstream.

*If* that is not quite the case here, here is one approach:

```
- (void)undo
{
   if (0 == self.pathArray.count) {
     self.drawImage.image = nil;
     return;
   }

   self.drawImage.image = self.pathArray.lastObject;
   [self.pathArray removeLastObject];
}
```

As well, `[pathArray removeLastObjectatIndex:];` is not a real selector.

**Update**

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691096/resolving-exc-bad-access-issue-in-cocoa/7691260#7691260) to enable and find zombies, and locate the reference count offset quickly. Your program should never message a zombie.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work and currently I have this in my program. But my app falls on this - [pathArray removeLastObjectatIndex:0];

Comment: @RadimHalfar I added: "[pathArray removeLastObjectatIndex:]; is not a real selector." in an edit.

Comment: sorry my mistake, i meant this [pathArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];

Comment: @RadimHalfar ok - Run with Zombies enabled in Instruments. If that fails, run with Guard Malloc enabled

Comment: neither zombies nor guard helped..:(

Comment: with zombie this report : An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated object (zombie) at address: 0xab19a00.